# What's variable about a world made from a world seed?

Tags: terraria

What's variable about a world made from a world seed?

I'm trying to get a [Celebrationmk10](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Celebrationmk10) world so I can buy Sandstorms in Bottles from the Princess, and the Wiki's map shows a Pyramid basically near the center of its world, but mine is basically all Crimson?

Is that due to being a Master Mode, Large World? I don't think the Difficulty affects the world, but the Size would...

So, why is that? Even though they're presumably both using the Celebrationmk10 seed.

Answer (score 6):

These seeds do not seem to function the same way regular seeds do. Normally, when you enter the same seed twice, it will just be used by the world generator to create the same world both times (assuming identical settings). But when you enter a special word like celebrationmk10, all it does is trigger the world generator to enter a different "mode", where special rules are applied to how the world is generated. For the actual terrain, ores, treasure chest and everything else, it presumably uses a completely random seed under the hood, as if you had left it blank. So getting an identical Celebrationmk10 twice would either require a lot of luck, or some kind of trick I'm personally not aware of.